# Howler throws 'Decoding audio data failed' when used inside electron

Tags: javascript, electron, web-audio-api, howler.js

I'm trying to load an audio file using Howler.js inside an Electron app, on the renderer process.

```
new Howl({
  src: ['/path/to/audio/file.mp3'] 
)}
```

However, no matter what file type I'm trying to load, it always throws the same error inside Howler's `loaderror` event:

```
Decoding audio data failed.
```

I'm using Parcel to build a React based front end.
When I tried to remove them and start a new Electron project, loading & playing the audio files, from the same path, worked fine.

Those are the build commands:

```
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others --success first \"npm run parcel-dev\" \"npm run electron-dev\"",
"parcel-dev": "parcel ./src/index.html -d build/",
"electron-dev": "electron . --start-dev",
```

Comment: Is this in renderer or main? And can you add your code snippet?

Comment: I think this comes from the invalid src path

Comment: But I need to know how your project file structure and where your audio files are placed

Comment: @tpikachu I've added details about the build process

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue in my React app. I was able to fix it by importing the sound file at the top of the JavaScript file and passing the alias into the function.

```
import { Howl } from 'howler';
import soundFile from './sound-file.mp3'


export const sound = new Howl ({
  src: [soundFile],
  onload() {
    console.log("Sound is loaded.")
  },
  onloaderror(msg){
    console.log("NO SOUND!!!", msg)
  }
})
```